# Custom resource item type for xml constant

Tags: android, xml

I need special consts in the app. The resource item would be like this:

```
 <resources>
        <item type="myType" format="string" name="Name" >Some words</item>
        <item type="myType" format="string" name="Name1" >Some words</item>
        <item type="myType" format="string" name="Name2" >Some words</item>
 </resources>
```

And i would like to call it this way:

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/drawable"
            android:contentDescription:"@myType/Name" />
```

Any ideas how to do this? I checked a few sites but didn't bring me any solution.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Types are pre-defined and you cannot create your own. Why would you do so anyway? It appears you're just defining strings: `<item type="string" name="Name">Some words</item>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any ideas how to do this?

Build your own mobile OS and development toolchain. This may take some time and will limit the adoption of your app.

IOW, this is not possible with standard Android.

There are already "value" resource types for basic primitives (`int`, `float`, `boolean`) and `String`, in addition to the more complex standard structures like layouts and animations. If you need something other than those, you will need to come up with some other solution, such as:

- using your own custom XML in `res/xml/` and applying that XML via Java code at runtime
- code-generating standard resources from some other file format (e.g., custom XML) using a custom Gradle task, then use those code-generated resources no differently than if you had hand-written the generated resources yourself (e.g., it would still be `@string/foo`, not `@yourthingy/foo`)